# Sqlite kill app if table is empty while checking for exists row?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am facing problem with Sqlite only if I want to check for row existence.

If table is empty then application should be killed and closed by android. I have tried to trace the problem but I couldn't find it , where is the problem in my code ?

This is the row check existence function in my Sql class:

```
 public boolean clExists( String email )
      {

          Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select 1 from "+TABLE_client+" where "+cl_email+"="+email, null);
          boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0) ? true : false;
           cursor.close();
          return exists;

      }
```

and this is where I execute the code ( jsinfo.getString("email") ) a email String return from Json array and its not empty

```
datasource.open();
if ( datasource.clExists(jsinfo.getString("email")))
{
    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "exists "+jsinfo.getString("email"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}else
{
    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "not exists "+jsinfo.getString("email"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}    
datasource.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need literal between email

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select 1 from "+TABLE_client
                                 +" where "+cl_email+"='"+email+"'", null);
```

Comment: yes correct i forgot to do that its works fine now :) thanks bro